# What are some Coldfusion (mx7 and greater) "Gotchas" that I should know about?

Tags: coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Common programming mistakes for ColdFusion programmer to avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191131/common-programming-mistakes-for-coldfusion-programmer-to-avoid)

I just spent half the day troubleshooting what is apparently a rather famous gotcha for Coldfusion MX7 and below:

**The nested query loop bug:**

Where you are required to reference the `current_row` of the outer query or else you will only see the first record.

For example:

```
<cfloop query="outer">
  <cfloop query="innner">
    <p>#outer.field#</p><!--- this won't work, you'll only get the first row --->
    <p>#outer.field[current_row]#</p><!--- you must do this instead --->
  </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

**Are there any other ways in which ColdFusion does not work in the obvious way?**

Comment: I don't know that that's really a bug, and CF has worked that way for _ages_. It wasn't introduced in CF7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Arrays are pass-by-value!
- case-sensitive for certain ORM related operations / annotations
- `serializeJSON()` may* mess up your data unexpectedly e.g.`'yes' --> 'true'`, `1 --> 1.0`
- `<cfdump>` may not be telling you the truth
- `null` and `[empty string]` is the same in a query object
- CF9 doesn't support SOAP 1.2 very well, wait til CF10 arrives
- some structs looks like structs, but they're not really struct (e.g. `cfcatch` )
- remote methods will get invoked in a new instance of the containing CFC, so don't count on instance variables being ready to be used
- `var` scope doesn't work as well as `local.` sometimes when it is defined multiple times in the same function
- the ternary operator may evaluate your inline array/structure literal and throw exception if things inside that array/structure is not defined
- `<cfparam name="foo" default="#bar()#">`, `bar()` is always invoked even though foo is defined
- might accidentally run into undocumented reserved words: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2011/5/9/Interesting-issue-with-reserved-function-names-inside-CFCs
- CF ajax tags and jQuery don't mix
- more here: [Common programming mistakes for ColdFusion programmer to avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191131/common-programming-mistakes-for-coldfusion-programmer-to-avoid/1191158#1191158)
- and even more here: [Things to watch out for in ColdFusion 9 with CF-ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480377/things-to-watch-out-for-in-coldfusion-9-with-cf-orm/2480456#2480456)